# Excel VBA querying from Password-Protected Access Database

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am currently trying to query one of the table from Microsoft Access Database (.mdb), however, when I try to do a `SELECT * FROM myTable`, it gives an "User-defined type not defined". May I know why?

Here's my sample code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim dbPath As String
    Dim aQuery As String
    Dim pword As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    dbPath = ThisWorkBook.Path & "\Database.mdb"
    pword = "password"
    aQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable"

    Set db = Access.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(dbPath, True, False, ";PWD=" & pword)
    Set rs = db.Execute(aQuery)
    rs.MoveFirst
    MsgBox rs.Fields(0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does your code break? Which line?

Comment: If you're doing this from Excel then you need to add a reference to the DAO object library.

Answer (score 2):

Using ADO

Add Reference:  Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library

---

```
Sub test()

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dbPath As String
    Dim aQuery As String
    Dim pword As String
    Dim strcon As String


    dbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database.mdb"
    pword = "abcd"
    aQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable"

    strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
            & "Data Source=" & dbPath & ";" _
            & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & pword & ";"

    Conn.Open strcon
    rs.Open aQuery, Conn

    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        MsgBox rs.Fields(0)
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Using DAO 
Add Reference:  Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library

As @Tim highlighted you have missed adding the reference to library.

```
Sub test()

   Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim dbPath As String
    Dim aQuery As String
    Dim pword As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    dbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database.mdb"
    pword = "abcd"
    aQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable"


    Set db = OpenDatabase(dbPath, True, False, ";PWD=" & pword)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(aQuery)
    rs.MoveFirst
    MsgBox rs.Fields(0)

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim db As object, rs as object
    Dim dbPath As String
    Dim aQuery As String
    Dim pword As String, uid as string

    dbPath = ThisWorkBook.Path & "\Database.mdb"
    pword = "password"
    uid = "myid"

    set db = createobject("adodb.connection")
    with db.open
        .Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & _
        ";User ID=" & uid & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=""" & pword & """;"
    end with
    aQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable"

    Set rs = db.Execute(aQuery)
    rs.MoveFirst
    MsgBox rs.Fields(0)

    db.close
    set rs = nothing
    set db = nothing
End Sub
```