# How to declare the password to connect from Excel to a password protected Access File

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, passwords

```
Sub Update_Record()

Dim accApp As Object
Dim InvoiceX As String, ResolutionX As String
InvoiceX = Sheets("NG1").Range("B8")
ResolutionX = Sheets("NG1").Range("G11")
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "UPDATE [T01] SET [T01].Resolution = '" & ResolutionX & "' WHERE "
SQL = SQL & "((([T01].Invoice)=" & InvoiceX & "));"
Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With accApp
    .OpenCurrentDataBase "\\MyDataBase.accdb"
    .DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
    .Quit
End With
Set accApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

'The following code works perfectly. But it asks me for the password every time:  Where and how should I add my password to the code?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471759/excel-vba-querying-from-password-protected-access-database

Comment: or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037493/excel-adodb-vba-error-msg-not-a-valid-password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA querying from Password-Protected Access Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471759/excel-vba-querying-from-password-protected-access-database)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I guess I will try to remake the code with the samples you shared.